# How can I check the type of CFPropertyList?

Tags: cocoa, macos, core-foundation

When using the `CFPreferences` API to store and retrieve per user and machine wide app settings on Mac OS X, the `CFPreferencesCopyAppValue` returns a `CFPropertyListRef` to represent the retrieved setting.

I can't seem to find code that lets me safely test that the `CFPropertyList` is actually a `CFString` so I can trust that the result is the string I am looking for.

Whats the proper method for transforming CFPropertyList objects back into `CFString` / `CFNumber` / `CFWhateverElse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`CFGetTypeID`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTypeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CFTypeID) function:

```
if (CFGetTypeID(myPropertyListRef) == CFStringGetTypeID()) {
    // it's really a string!
}
```

Comment: I was looking for a CFPropertyListGetTypeID. Sheesh. Thanks.